# Node.js options for storing data as file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, data-storage, file-storage

Simple open-ended question. I have an array of 40000 zip code entries with latitude and longitude entries.

It's currently in a 2.5MB CSV file.

If I wanted to run this on AWS, what would be the recommended method for storing this data?  I could just read via fs and parse the CSV to a JS object every time I need to access the data, but how would you handle this?

The use case is that a user enters a zip code and a distance, and the program returns all zip codes within that distance.

Comment: [You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, __open-ended questions__ diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: This is normally a task you would solve using a database that support geometric types and an index on them that supports such queries.  But you could also solve this without database with an own index structure.

Comment: @PatrickEvans speaking of that, where would the best place be to ask these kinds of questions?

Comment: FWIW, I'd start with a database that can handle geospacial data and let it do the heavy lifting: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/geospatial-queries/.

Comment: @Chris Maybe, https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: 2.5 MB is a small amount of data and 40,000 records is easy to index. The entire data set could be cached in memory. I would use a file backed, memory based database such a sqlite.